# how can i display translation in data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, translation, vuex, vuetify.js

reference : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization#custom-components

If I run `console.log(this.$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.selectProvince'))` in method or mounted, it works. But if I run it on data, it does not works. for example :

```
data: () => ({
  cards: [
    { id: 1, title: this.$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.selectProvince') },
  ],
})
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable in the data function and point to the current Vue instance, then you can use it as follows:

```
data() {
  const self = this
  return {
    cards: [
      { id: 1, title: self.$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.selectProvince') }
    ]
  }
}
```